# Scrolling on IPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I have the next code:

```
> <div class="scroller" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow:
> auto; overflow-y: hidden;">
>     <div class="content" style="height: 100%; width: 2500px;">
>         <div id="vScrollDiv" style="width: 500px; height: 100%; overflow: auto; color: #fff; display: inline-block">
>             Content that makes div overflow verticaly
>         </div>
>         <div style="width: 1900px; height: 100%; color: #000; display: inline-block">
>             Content that makes "scroller" div overflow horizontaly
>         </div>
>     </div>
```

How can I scroll horizontally the content div when my finger is over the div that scrolls only vertically and I gesture like I want to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to catch the touch events and scroll the right divs by identifying "clicked" div and calculating the trajectory of the drag.
More infos about the touch events:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html
Scrolling made with:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

if i interpret your question right... you want to simulate the mousewheel with horizontally scroll. Thats not a feature of ipad i guess. if you move your fingers to scroll into a direction it will do that if possible... but as you overflow is hidden it will ignore it. i think this is not possible with some web-code. did i undestand that question right?